# PHP - Stuck with this regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
<?php

echo preg_replace( '/( \* Version:[ ]+)([0-9\.]{6})/',  '${1}' . '6.6.6' , ' * Version:           3.1.0' );
```

I basically want to detect the line with the Version and replace it with a new version. I not get why it is not working

Comment: What test data? The test data is the 3rd argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This subexpression...

```
([0-9\.]{6})
```

... will only match if there's *exactly* 6 target characters. But there's just 5 of them in `3.1.0` string (3 digits, two dots).

The easiest way to fix it is to change that subexpression to...

```
([0-9.]{1,6})
```

... so it'll match *up to* 6 characters. I've also removed the preceding backslash here: you don't need to escape `.` symbol within a character class (it doesn't have any special meaning here).

Comment: To only match OPs data it would rather be `([0-9.]{5})` http://regex101.com/r/cD7qJ2. Otherwise `([0-9.]{2,})` might be a good idea.

Comment: Agreed. In fact, to cover proper versioning only, something like `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9])*` looks more suitable.

Comment: Lol tanks, I am bad a counting I guess.